# XSLT view is not working in Chrome Broswer

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Below code of html file is successfully viewed in IE and Firefox. But not view in chrome browser. Also written in java-script for supporting the xsl to transform on chrome browser. Can anyone solve this?

I have placed code below xml, xslt and html files. check and provide any errors occured.

**1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
<title>Empire Burlesque</title>
<artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
<country>USA</country>
<company>Columbia</company>
<price>10.90</price>
<year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Hide your heart</title>
<artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>CBS Records</company>
<price>9.90</price>
<year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Greatest Hits</title>
<artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
<country>USA</country>
<company>RCA</company>
<price>9.90</price>
<year>1982</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Still got the blues</title>
<artist>Gary Moore</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>Virgin records</company>
<price>10.20</price>
<year>1990</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Eros</title>
<artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
<country>EU</country>
<company>BMG</company>
<price>9.90</price>
<year>1997</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>One night only</title>
<artist>Bee Gees</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>Polydor</company>
<price>10.90</price>
<year>1998</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Sylvias Mother</title>
<artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>CBS</company>
<price>8.10</price>
<year>1973</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Maggie May</title>
<artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>Pickwick</company>
<price>8.50</price>
<year>1990</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Romanza</title>
<artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
<country>EU</country>
<company>Polydor</company>
<price>10.80</price>
<year>1996</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>When a man loves a woman</title>
<artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
<country>USA</country>
<company>Atlantic</company>
<price>8.70</price>
<year>1987</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Black angel</title>
<artist>Savage Rose</artist>
<country>EU</country>
<company>Mega</company>
<price>10.90</price>
<year>1995</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
<artist>Many</artist>
<country>USA</country>
<company>Grammy</company>
<price>10.20</price>
<year>1999</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>For the good times</title>
<artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>Mucik Master</company>
<price>8.70</price>
<year>1995</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Big Willie style</title>
<artist>Will Smith</artist>
<country>USA</country>
<company>Columbia</company>
<price>9.90</price>
<year>1997</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Tupelo Honey</title>
<artist>Van Morrison</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>Polydor</company>
<price>8.20</price>
<year>1971</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Soulsville</title>
<artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
<country>Norway</country>
<company>WEA</company>
<price>7.90</price>
<year>1996</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>The very best of</title>
<artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>Island</company>
<price>8.90</price>
<year>1990</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Stop</title>
<artist>Sam Brown</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>A and M</company>
<price>8.90</price>
<year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Bridge of Spies</title>
<artist>T`Pau</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>Siren</company>
<price>7.90</price>
<year>1987</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Private Dancer</title>
<artist>Tina Turner</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>Capitol</company>
<price>8.90</price>
<year>1983</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Midt om natten</title>
<artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
<country>EU</country>
<company>Medley</company>
<price>7.80</price>
<year>1983</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
<artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>DECCA</company>
<price>9.90</price>
<year>1991</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>The dock of the bay</title>
<artist>Otis Redding</artist>
<country>USA</country>
<company>Stax Records</company>
<price>7.90</price>
<year>1968</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Picture book</title>
<artist>Simply Red</artist>
<country>EU</country>
<company>Elektra</company>
<price>7.20</price>
<year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Red</title>
<artist>The Communards</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>London</company>
<price>7.80</price>
<year>1987</year>
</cd>
<cd>
<title>Unchain my heart</title>
<artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
<country>USA</country>
<company>EMI</company>
<price>8.20</price>
<year>1987</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

**v.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
<th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
<tr>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else 
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("1.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("v.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Browsers natively don't support XSLT 2 or 3, only XSLT 1. And Chrome is known to have default security settings that prevent local file system access so if your code does not work with Chrome, is that in the case that you try to load all those files from the local file system? Or do you load over HTTP(S)? If so, any error in the Chrome console?

Comment: Your code specifies version="2.0", but it is not actually using any XSLT 2.0 features. An XSLT 1.0 processor is supposed to work in those circumstances, but perhaps Chrome is objecting to that. There's a lot more diagnostics available in the Chrome developer console than some people realise. (If you actually need XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, use Saxon-JS).